# Function only adding textContent in one of my divs

Tags: javascript

```js
const player = (name, symbol) => {
  return { name, symbol };
};

const Player1 = player("Player1", "X");
const Player2 = player("Player2", "O");
console.log(Player1);


for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  const getBoard = document.getElementById("board");
  const createBoard = document.createElement("div");
  getBoard.appendChild(createBoard);
  createBoard.className = "game-board";
}

function createPItem(name) {
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = name;
  p.className = "text";
  return p;
}

const board = document.querySelector(".game-board");

board.addEventListener("click", selectBoard);

function selectBoard() {
  board.appendChild(createPItem(`${Player1.symbol}`));
  board.className = "complete-board";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fffdfa;
}

.title {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
}

.player-turn {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fffdfa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
}

.board div,
.complete-board {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #3c4048;
  width: 175px;
  height: 150px;
}

.board div:hover {
  background-color: #f4e06d;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.8s;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.complete-board {
  background-color: #f4e06d !important;
}

.text {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4649ff;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Poor Story", cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.parallelogram {
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.skew-fix {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">Tic Tac Toe</p>
      <p class="player-turn">Player X turn</p>
      <div id="board" class="board"></div>
      <a id="btn" class="btn parallelogram">
        <span class="skew-fix">Reset ></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm making Tic Tac Toe and I have a function that creates two players, assigning a symbol to each of them.

```
const player = (name, symbol) => {
  return { name, symbol };
};

const Player1 = player("Player1", "X");
const Player2 = player("Player2", "O");
```

I also have this HTML which creates a board

```
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">Tic Tac Toe</p>
      <p class="player-turn">Player X turn</p>
      <div id="board" class="board"></div>
    </div>
```

and using a combination of `display: flex` and this for loop I create 9 divs that fit perfectly inside the game board.

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  const getBoard = document.getElementById("board");
  const createBoard = document.createElement("div");
  getBoard.appendChild(createBoard);
  createBoard.className = "game-board";
}
```

I have a function that creates a `p` element & assigns a class to it to get the proper font-size.

```
function createPItem(name) {
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = name;
  p.className = "text";
  return p;
}
```

And finally an eventListener that selects the `gameBoard` class that I click on and adds some text.

```
const board = document.querySelector(".game-board");

board.addEventListener("click", selectBoard);

function selectBoard() {
  board.appendChild(createPItem(`${Player1.symbol}`));
  board.className = "complete-board";
}
```

When I click the first div inside my `board` class, the above code works perfect and creates / assigns the `p` tag. Inside the `p` tag is the letter "X" which is what I want to happen. But when I click on any other div, nothing happens and I don't know why.

**What I've tried**

I've tried a combination of several different things, including changing the for loop to give each div a class name like `board${i}` but not only does that seem tacky, it didn't actually work and instead filled in every divs textContent all at once.

Comment: Please combine the codes to a runnable [mre].

Comment: Could you convert your code into a snippet?

Comment: 0stone0 and @i-drink-dirty-code yes I can & just did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you use `querySelector(".game-board")`, which will only select the **first** `.game-board` element. You need to use `querySelectorAll()` to find all elements with that class, and then loop over them to add the event handler.

In addition the `selectBoard()` function needs to be amended to accept the `Event` object as an argument so you can get a reference to the clicked element without relying on global variables:

```js
const board = document.querySelectorAll(".game-board");
board.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", selectBoard));

function selectBoard(e) {
  e.target.appendChild(createPItem(`${Player1.symbol}`));
  e.target.className = "complete-board";
}
```

Here's a full working version:

```js
const player = (name, symbol) => ({ name, symbol });

const Player1 = player("Player1", "X");
const Player2 = player("Player2", "O");

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  const getBoard = document.querySelector("#board");
  const createBoard = document.createElement("div");
  getBoard.appendChild(createBoard);
  createBoard.className = "game-board";
}

function createPItem(name) {
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = name;
  p.className = "text";
  return p;
}

const board = document.querySelectorAll(".game-board");
board.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", selectBoard));

function selectBoard(e) {
  e.target.appendChild(createPItem(`${Player1.symbol}`));
  e.target.className = "complete-board";
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', selectBoard); // prevent additional clicks
}
```

```css
#board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#board .game-board,
#board .complete-board {
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
}

#board .complete-board {
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="board" class="board"></div>
```

Comment: ah, no wonder I couldn't get it to work. Thank you so much this worked perfectly!

Comment: Why not work with a delegate listener since you've already adjusted the click listener code to work like that?